# Primefaces splitButton rendering issue when no text is on the button

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

My `splitButton` should not have any text on the button. So when I try to achieve this using by providing blank value for the `value` attribute, the button shrinks to a very small size. I want it to remain the size of the dropdown button which appears beside it. I don't have an `actionListener`, therefore I need the button to display no text.

Is there no default size set to the button when it contains no text? Or is it possible to apply a style property to it?

Comment: Did you try with `value="&nbsp;"`?

Comment: @partlov - I am getting the following exception **The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared.**

Comment: Ok, that is XML problem, try with `&#160;` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the value attribute like this:

```
value="&#160;"
```